# Using Step Function for Synchronizing Primay Data Source with Secondary Data Sources and trigger Actions based on Data Updates

Tags: design-patterns, redis, architecture, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have an application which acts as Data Layer and is responsible for performing all the CRUD operation on the database. Due to availability issue, we maintain Redis cache over it, which will ultimately act as the secondary data source. Hitting primary data sources frequently leads to throttling and latency issues.

Certain actions also gets triggered on the basis of updates published to the DataBase.

I am trying to abstract out the secondary data source updates and actions triggered on the basis of these updates from the data access layer to [serverless architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttwF2.jpg).

Is the step-function best suited for the mentioned usecase? Or I should think of different architecture?

[Current Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfmtu.jpg)

Comment: Can you give us more information about the primary Data Source? What kind of Database is it? - If you're lucky enough to use DynamoDB, DynamoDB streams and/or DAX might me a suitable option.

Comment: Primay Data Source is not AWS based and is internal to my company. @Maurice I am planning to pass on the changes done to Primary Data Source to Step Function using SQS-Lambda

Comment: I'm still not sure how your architecture currently looks... - A solution for this might be some kind of write-through-caching behavior, which means your application would write all changes to Redis and the DB, which means all new updates are always in present in Redis - although this may waste memory if changed data is infrequently accessed. If you can give us more information about your use case we might be able to provide better solutions - if possible a small diagram would probably help.

Comment: @Maurice I have updated the question with the current architecture as well as the architecture I am thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your proposed architecture, which looks as follows, I don't think step functions are necessary.

[image: Proposed Architecture]

I'd use SNS to fan out updates to multiple SQS queues:

- Queue #1 triggers a lambda function, that updates your data in Redis
- Queue #2 is used for Client-Updates (whatever this means in your case)

I don't see the reason to use Step Functions here as SQS makes sure, that each message gets processed **at least** once.

```
          +----------+
     +---->Primary DB|
     |    +----------+      +----------------+      +------------+    +-----+
     +                      |                |      |            |    |     |
Change                +----->  SQS-Queue #1  +------>   Lambda   +---->Redis|
     +                |     |                |      |            |    |     |
     |                |     +----------------+      +------------+    +-----+
     |    +-----------+
     |    |           |
     +---->   SNS     |
          |           |
          +-----------+
                      |     +----------------+
                      |     |                |
                      +-----> SQS-Queue #2   | <------ Clients
                            |                |
                            +----------------+
```

I think SNS might be more suited to push updates to your clients as well, as SQS is pull-based.

Comment: For the status tracking of each updates and retrying failed execution I thought of using Step Function.

Comment: You could do that and it may be suitable depending on how complex your data structures are. But it may be sufficient to use the [Visibility Timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html) of SQS to ensure, that messages get processed again, if the first attempt fails. To be clear: Step functions will work, but if you should use them depends on what you want to optimize for: Speed, Reliability, Cost, Maintainability,...

Comment: Speed, Reliability are what is expected out of the architecture and the messages put to the queue needs to be transformed into some structure before dumping to SQS or Redis. Thats why thought of using Step Function.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AWS Step Functions FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/faqs/):

> You should consider **AWS Step Functions** when you need to coordinate
> service components in the development of highly scalable and ***auditable***
> applications. You should consider using **Amazon Simple Queue Service**
> **(Amazon SQS)**, when you need a ***reliable***, highly scalable, ***hosted queue***
> for sending, storing, and receiving messages between services. Step
> Functions keeps track of all tasks and events in an application.
> Amazon SQS requires you to implement your own application-level
> tracking, especially if your application uses multiple queues. The
> Step Functions Console and visibility APIs provide an
> application-centric view that lets you search for executions, drill
> down into an execution’s details, and administer executions. Amazon
> SQS requires implementing such additional functionality. Step
> Functions offers several features that facilitate application
> development, such as passing data between tasks and flexibility in
> distributing tasks. ***Amazon SQS requires you to implement some
> application-level functionality***. While you can use Amazon SQS to build
> basic workflows to coordinate your distributed application, you can
> get this facility out-of-the-box with Step Functions, alongside other
> application-level capabilities.

So, at first sight it seems that the answer is use Step Functions if you can afford it (based on costs). But looking at the differences (that I have empathized with bold font in the documentation text) some important questions arise from your needs:

1. Is the order of processing important ? Do you want to prevent one record that come first to be processed after one that come later ?
2. Is the order of insertion in the secondary data source important ?

If the answer is yes for any of the questions I guess that you might need one SQS queue at the beginning and one at the end of the step functions workflow.

Note that if the data chunks transferred are not big, and they are very frequent, it might be better to use [AWS Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/) Data Streams and [AWS Kinesis Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/). In case you still decide to use Step Functions for high event rates and short duration, choose *Express Workflows* over *Standard Workflows*.

In any case it is always better to call AWS consultants and provide more details of what you want to achieve, and they would ask you the important questions in order to give you one advice.